# Setting Slim parameters in order to debug

Tags: php, rest, debugging, slim, phped

I enjoy using Slim, but am frustrated on how to debug it.  Lets say I have the following routing.  I can do a cURL request, and see the output, but instead I wish to go through the script line by line with my IDE debugger which happens to be NuShere's phpED.  While I haven't quick figured it out, I am pretty sure I can make phpED do a POST request, but definitely not a PUT or DELETE request, so there is no point.

Is there any way to do so?  I can force `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` to any value easy enough, and can also change the `$_GET` superglobal, but body data (i.e. `$_POST`) isn't so simple.

```
<?php
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/books/:id', function ($id) {
    //Show book identified by $id
});
$app->post('/books', function () {
    //Create book
});
$app->put('/books/:id', function ($id) {
    //Update book identified by $id
});
$app->delete('/books/:id', function ($id) {
    //Delete book identified by $id
});
$app->get('/toys/:id', function ($id) {
    //Show toy identified by $id
});
$app->post('/toys', function () {
    //Create toy 
});
$app->put('/toys/:id', function ($id) {
    //Update toy identified by $id
});
$app->delete('/toys/:id', function ($id) {
    //Delete toy identified by $id
});
```

Comment: Often times there is some hidden input value for faking a verb in frameworks like this. Something generally like `<input type='hidden' name='method' value='put' />` or `name='_method'`

Comment: @Blake  That would be great if there were.

Comment: Have you read this: http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/put/ -- Refers to the hidden input required to change the verb there

Comment: Also, maybe you'll find more success using `PHP Xdebug` to debug your code.

Comment: Thanks Blake.  No, I hadn't noticed it, but am looking into it.  Also, I've thought about checking out Xdebug, bu haven't done so yet.  So, as far as an approach, I would..??..  Create a form with the appropriate action and inputs for the parameters and use the hidden input to set the method for each request I wish to test?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Blake's comments, I created the following method, and call it in a constructor.  After each request, a new test file is created which can be debug.

```
    private function createTest($params,$method)
    {
        $inputs=print_r($params,1);
        $method=strtolower($method);
        $method2=($method=='put' || $method=='delete')?'post':$method;
        $html=$this->createTestInputs($params,null,null); //array, previous inputs, name prefix
        $html=<<<eod
<p>URL: $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]</p>
<p>METHOD: $method</p>
<p>INPUTS:<pre>$inputs</pre></p>
<form action="$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" method="$method2">
    $html
    <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="$method"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Test"/>
</form>
eod;
        file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test.php', $html);
    }    

    private function createTestInputs($params,$html,$prefix)
    {
        foreach($params as $name=>$value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                $html=$this->createTestInputs($value,$html,$name);
            }
            else {
                $html.="<input name='".($prefix?$prefix.'['.$name.']':$name)."' type='hidden' value='$value' />\n";
            }
        }
        return $html;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If You need debug info in case of exception:

```
$app->config('debug', true);
```

also You can use Firebug + FirePHP as explained here:  https://www.sitepoint.com/debug-php-firebug-firephp/

**Tracy**
but I like the interface of debugging so I found something like this: https://github.com/nette/tracy

checkout this gist: https://gist.github.com/1f7/b2d2846777e71f48e43a2ef7acc0a655 (it has little bugs in example, but You can handle it)

demo is here: https://nette.github.io/tracy/tracy-debug-bar.html

screenshot of my test implementation:

[image: screenshot]

but I really recommend You to use normal IDE like `PHPStorm` and debug Your app like a boss (:

watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqDDJfG6ip4  or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_U8xrj0-PXU

p.s. for question of properly configuring Tracy, write in comment (;

Answer (score 0):

Slim3 Tracy [gist](https://gist.github.com/1f7/b2d2846777e71f48e43a2ef7acc0a655) increased to [Slim3 Debug Bar package](https://packagist.org/packages/runcmf/runtracy).

[image: Slim3 Debug Bar]
More screenshots [here](https://bitbucket.org/1f7/runtracy.git).

And i agree - PHPStorm is better for debug, but quick discover vars easier in Tracy.

In the near future plan add Echo Console (JQuery Terminal)
[image: Slim3 Debug Bar Terminal example]